# punycode and .рф cyrillic domain redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, ascii, idn, punycode

I have a website with cyrillic domain name. There is an authorization lib which redirects the user to login page, but the url is somehow missformed.

The website is on CodeIgniter and the redirect function used is the standard redirect function of 
the codeigniter. I have modified a bit 
and it looks now like this

```
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'location', $http_response_code = 302)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('#^https?://#ui', $uri))
    {
        $uri = site_url($uri);
    }


    //exit(idn_to_ascii($uri));
    switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=http://".idn_to_ascii($uri));
            break;
        default         : header("Location:http://".idn_to_ascii($uri), TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

idn_to_ascii functions seems not rightly coding the UTF url string ...

Can anybody hint a solution?

Instead of

```
http://xn-------63dat7alb0aizbbjcoujt7j3a6e.xn--p1ai/auth/admin/
```

I get

```
xn-------63dat7alb0aizbbjcoujt7j3a6e.xn--/auth/login-foj4c
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your code a bit and use `idn_to_ascii()` only on domain part and not on the full url.

instead of:

```
switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=http://".idn_to_ascii($uri));
            break;
        default         : header("Location:http://".idn_to_ascii($uri), TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
```

you should use:

```
$pos = mb_strpos($uri,'/', null, 'UTF8');

if ($pos === false) { // only domain, no slash here
    $uri = idn_to_ascii($uri);
}
else { // changes only for domain part, rest left unchanged
    $uri = idn_to_ascii(mb_substr($uri,0,$pos, 'UTF-8')).mb_substr($uri,$pos,null, 'UTF-8');
}


switch($method)
    {
        case 'refresh'  : header("Refresh:0;url=http://".$uri);
            break;
        default         : header("Location:http://".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
            break;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Test code just for generating URL:

```
<?php

$uri = 'помощь-от-сглаза-и-порчи.рф/auth/admin/';

$pos = mb_strpos($uri,'/', null, 'UTF8');

if ($pos === false) {
    $uri = idn_to_ascii($uri);
}
else {
    $uri = idn_to_ascii(mb_substr($uri,0,$pos, 'UTF-8')).mb_substr($uri,$pos,null, 'UTF-8');
}

echo $uri."<br />";
```

Output for this is: `xn-------63dat7alb0aizbbjcoujt7j3a6e.xn--p1ai/auth/admin/` as expected I think - when I copy this text into browser I get redirected again to `http://помощь-от-сглаза-и-порчи.рф/auth/admin/`

Comment: Something is wrong with mb_subst as it cuts out latinic part totally and always I get redirected to the root ... any ideas why?

Comment: I have used $uri=str_replace("http://","",$uri);
  $uriA=explode("/",$uri);
  
  $uriA[0]=idn_to_ascii($uriA[0]);
  
  $uri = "http://".implode("/",$uriA);  and it worked!

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek The code about does not works for me; so i've used the more compact  `$hostname = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_HOST);
$punycode = idn_to_ascii($hostname);
$uri   = str_ireplace($hostname, $punycode, $uri);`